# Ошибка валидации markdown

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, markdown

#### Описание

Есть вот этот код:

```js
function number(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

Если посмотреть его markdown как строку будет:

```js
"\`\`\`\nfunction number(min, max) {\n\treturn Math.random() * (max - min) + min;\n}\n\`\`\`"
```

Ну логично, что код написанный мною валидируется как код, поэтому его структуру можно описать этим regex:

````js
/```.*?```/gm
````

Но почему-то строка не проходит проверку regex:

````js
const string = "\`\`\`\nfunction number(min, max) {\n\treturn Math.random() * (max - min) + min;\n}\n\`\`\`";
const regex = /```.*?```/gm;
console.log(regex.test(string));
````

#### Вопрос

Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (Точка, десятичная запятая) сопоставляется с любым символом за
> исключением символов новой строки: \n, \r, \u2028 или \u2029.

````js
const string = "\`\`\`\nfunction number(min, max) {\n\treturn Math.random() * (max - min) + min;\n}\n\`\`\`";
const regex = /```[\s\S]*?```/gm;
console.log(regex.test(string));
````

Answer (score 2):

Для захвата метасимволом `.` перевода строки можно так же добавить модификатор `s` - single line.

````js
const string = "\`\`\`\nfunction number(min, max) {\n\treturn Math.random() * (max - min) + min;\n}\n\`\`\`";
const regex = /```.*?```/gms;
console.log(regex.test(string));
````

Comment: Ответ хороший. Плюс за это, но галочку не смогу изменить.

Comment: @eccs0103, этого и не требуется, предыдущий ответ так же является верным, мой ответ как дополнение. Спасибо